# How to store objects with the same structure vut with different values in my sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an stdClass object that I need to store in my sql tables. The thing is since I am new there is something I do not understand. I got the values I need to store but the question is how do I store multiple objects with the same keys but with different values in one table? Do I build many queries?
The values I have look like this:

- course name: literature
- first name :Princess
- last name: Okafor
- age:29
- first name: Liliane
- last name :Mbadi
- age 26
- List item
- first name Beatrice
- last name Otanji
- student age 28

Could anybody please give me an idea about how I can store all the students?

Comment: Are you asking for table structure or PHP code?

Comment: I already have two tables. The tables courses and students. I am asking how I can store all students in the database using php

Comment: Have tried anything so far? please post it so we can take a look at it

Comment: I will edit the main post so that I have enough space to write what I have

Comment: You insert rows. Each object = 1 row.

Comment: How do you mean ? do I build many queries like

Comment: So basically, you literally know nothing about this topic? Is this a class assignment or something else? You can "build many queries", you can create one query, you can build prepared statements - the problem is that we have no clue where you're stuck. On this site, we need to see **what you tried** - currently, it seems you tried nothing. Try building many queries for start and then check if that works.

Comment: I loop to get values and then I store them but the thing is I do not really know how to store each student once. It stores students several times.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are looking for is a many to many relationship since you have courses and students, since many students can take many subjects. So what you need is a table between them to connect the two tables. You could create a table `course_student` having the columns `course_id` and `student_id` which have foreign key constraints to id in the course and student tables

Comment: I already have them. My problem is how to store the students one by one as contained in the std CLass object. I have loops but they store data anyhow and more than once . They look like this

Comment: You need to include the code you have for storing the data so we can see what you are doing